# How to change a variable (constant) used in a class and update this class to use the new value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary

I've been trying to solve this for hours and cannot get to a solution.

I use equations which I define inside a class. These equations depend on constants, which I've defined as variables.
My ultimate goal is to be able to change and iterate one of the constants and as such update the equations which are dependent on these constants (variable).

As an example:

```
constant_1 = 10
constant_2 = 20

class(object):
    first_eq = constant_1 * constant_2

# I now want to update constant_2 to 40 and thus first_eq should change its value
```

Things I've tried:

- Using dictionaries list to store my constants and update the pretended value at the the end of the file
- Use different files for the constants and equations and then import them into a new file and then try to change the constant from that file
- Define functions to update (I can include the defined functions if needed) the value on the constants file and them in the new file when I import the constants I use that function to update the file (I've tried for both constants defined in a dictionary or inside a class)
- Some more things I don't remember already

All these methods work in changing the constant (variable) I want, however the value of the equation always stays the same.

Any help ?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
As suggested I'll insert here the part of my code relevant to this discussion. My aim is to be able to change a given constant (variable) which may be present in one or more equations and have the value of these equation update accordingly.

My constants file is:

```
from PySpice.Unit import *
from PySpice.Physics.PhysicalConstants import *
import numpy as np
import math

constants = {
    "conv" : 1.0e3,
    "T" : 25+273.15,
    "k" : 1.380650e-23,
    "PI" : np.pi,
    "PI2" : np.pi*2.0,
    "q" : 1.602176e-19,
    "NAv" : 6.0221415e23,
    "dWaals" : 0.34e-9,
    "eps0" : 8.854187e-12,
    "epsw" : 78.5,
    "epslys" : 3.0,
    "epsglyco" : 81,
    "ros" : 0.7,
    "roAu" : 2.27e-8,
    "roglyco" : 1.6e6,
    "Cbulk" : 150.0e-3
}
constants["ET"] = constants["q"]/(constants["k"]*constants["T"])

constants["epsmed"] = constants["eps0"]*constants["epsw"]

constants_neuron = {
    "Ncomp" : 5.0,
    "dsomat" : 100.0e-6,
    "daxont" : 10.0e-6,
    "laxont" : 500.0e-6,
    "Rax" : 0.1
}

constants_gme = {
    "phstalk" : 1.0,
    "dmstalk" : 1.0e-6,  # MUDAR PARA d_stalk : 2um
    "hstalk" : 1.0e-6,
    "dmhead" : 2.0e-6,
    "tinsM" : 1.2,
}
constants_cleft = {
    "dsealjGME" : 2e-9,
    "alphahead" : 0.4294*np.pi,
    "Etawm" : 1.0,
    "deltawm" : 1.0,
    "deltawm" : 1.0,
}
```

And my equations' file is:

```
from PySpice.Unit import *
from PySpice.Physics.PhysicalConstants import *
import numpy as np
import math
from constants_spice import *
class parameters(object):




# **********************************************************************
# *               NEURON PARAMETERS
# **********************************************************************
# * laxont    Neuron axon length              [m]
# * daxont    Neuron axon diameter                [m]
# * dsomat    Neuron soma diameter                [m]
# * Rax       axoplasmatic resistance per unit length     [ohm*cm]
# * Ncomp     compartments number

    Asomat = (2.0*constants["PI2"]*(constants_neuron["dsomat"]/2.0)*(constants_neuron["dsomat"]/2.0))
    Aaxont = (constants["PI2"]*(constants_neuron["daxont"]/2.0)*constants_neuron["laxont"])
    ANEURt = (Asomat+Aaxont)
    dsoma = (constants_neuron["dsomat"]/constants_neuron["Ncomp"])
    daxon = constants_neuron["daxont"]
    laxon = (constants_neuron["laxont"]/constants_neuron["Ncomp"])
    Asoma = (2.0*constants["PI2"]*(dsoma/2.0)*(dsoma/2.0))
    Aaxon = (constants["PI2"]*(daxon/2.0)*laxon)
    ANEUR = (Asoma+Aaxon)

    # **********************************************************************
    # *               GME PARAMETERS
    # **********************************************************************
    # * phstalk   percentage of engulfed stalk height
    # * hstalk    GME stalk height                [m]
    # * htstalk   GME engulfed stalk height           [m]
    # * dmstalk   GME stalk diameter              [m]
    # * dmhead    GME head diameter               [m]
    # * Astalk    GME stalk area                  [m**2]
    # * Ahead     GME half head area              [m**2]
    # * Arim      GME rim area                    [m**2]
    # * AGME      GME total area                  [m**2]
    # * tinsM     thickness of the insulation coating     [m]

    htstalk = (constants_gme["hstalk"]*constants_gme["phstalk"])
    cirhead = (constants["PI2"]*((constants_gme["dmhead"])/2.0))
    Abstalk = (constants["PI"]*(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0)*(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0))
    Astalk = (constants["PI2"]*(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0)*htstalk)
    Aheadt = (2.0*constants["PI2"]*(constants_gme["dmhead"]/2.0)*(constants_gme["dmhead"]/2.0))
    Ahead = (Aheadt/2.0)
    Arim = (constants["PI"]*((constants_gme["dmhead"]/2.0)*(constants_gme["dmhead"]/2.0)-(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0)*(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0)))
    AGME = (Astalk+Ahead+Arim)

    # *-----------------------Rmicro---------------------------------------
    Rstalk = (constants["roAu"]*((htstalk) / (Abstalk)))
    Rhead = (constants["roAu"]) / (cirhead)
    RGME = (Rstalk+Rhead)
    RGME = RGME@u_Ω
    # * RGME = 20Meg
    # *-------------------------Shunt Capacitance--------------------------------------------
    PHIM = (constants["PI"]/2.0)
    CshGME = (((constants["PI2"]*constants["eps0"]*constants["epslys"])/np.log(constants_gme["tinsM"]))*(htstalk+(constants_gme["dmhead"]/2.0)*np.sin(PHIM)))
    CshGME = CshGME*10**12
    CshGME = CshGME@u_pF
    # print("CshGME = "+str(CshGME))
    # * + CshGME = 1.37e2p The shunt capacitance affects the recording! The Vpeak/
    # is saturated for the value of the article!
    # **********************************************************************
    # *               NUMBER of GMEs
    # **********************************************************************
    # * shxn      minimum distance between two GMEs head centers      [m]
    # * xGME      extra distance between two GMEs head centers        [m]
    # * shn       effective inter-GMEs head distance          [m]
    # * lambdaGME Debye length                        [m]
    # * nGME      number of vertically arranged GMEs in the soma compartment
    # *-----------------------------

    lambdaGME = (np.sqrt((constants["epsmed"]/(constants["q"]*constants["ET"]))*(1.0/(2.0*constants["NAv"]*constants["Cbulk"]*constants["conv"]))))
    lambdaGME = lambdaGME
    shxn = (constants_gme["dmhead"]+constants["dWaals"]+2.0*lambdaGME)
    xGME = 6.0e-6
    shn = (shxn+xGME)
    AmGME = (constants["PI"]*shn*shn)
    AmSOMA = (constants["PI"]*(dsoma/2.0)*(dsoma/2.0))
    nGME = (int(AmSOMA/AmGME))
    # **********************************************************************

    # **********************************************************************
    # *               GME CLEFT PARAMETERS
    # **********************************************************************
    # * dsealjGME cleft width at the neuron-GME junction          [m]
    # * alphahead head starting angle for resistor concentric rings model
    # * etawm     covering factor of the cross-sectional area of the solution.
    # * deltawm   surface overlapping coefficient: percentage of microel.
    # *               sensitive area covered by the neuron
    # *-----------------------------

    Rspreadhead = (((constants["ros"]/constants["PI2"])*(constants_cleft["dsealjGME"]/((constants_gme["dmhead"]/2.0)*((constants_gme["dmhead"]/2.0)+
    constants_cleft["dsealjGME"]))))*constants_cleft["Etawm"])
    H = (htstalk+(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0)+constants_cleft["dsealjGME"])
    Rspreadstalk = (((constants["ros"]/(constants["PI"]*H))*np.log((4.0*H)/(constants["PI2"]*(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0))))*constants_cleft["Etawm"])
    RspreadGME = (Rspreadhead+Rspreadstalk)
    RspreadGME = RspreadGME@u_Ohm
    rodj = (constants["ros"]/(constants["PI2"]*constants_cleft["dsealjGME"]))
    Rsealhead = (rodj*(np.log(np.tan(constants["PI"]/4.0))-np.log(np.tan(constants_cleft["alphahead"]/2.0))))
    Rsealrim = (rodj*(np.log((constants_gme["dmhead"]/2.0)/(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0))))
    Rsealstalk = (rodj*(htstalk/(constants_gme["dmstalk"]/2.0)))
    RsealGME = ((Rsealhead+Rsealrim+Rsealstalk)*constants_cleft["deltawm"])
    RsealGME = RsealGME@u_Ohm
    # print("Rseal="+str(RsealGME))
    # RsealGME = 100@u_GΩ
    # **********************************************************************
    # *
    # **********************************************************************
    # *       GME & GPE ELECTROLYTE INTERFACE PARAMETERS
    # **********************************************************************
    # * Chg       capacitance of EDL at the interface microel-solution    [F]
    # * Rhg       leakage resistance                  [ohm]
    # *-----------------------------
    # PEDOT:PSS PARAMETERS:
    ChgGME = 1.2@u_nF
    RhgGME = 10@u_MΩ

    # ChgGME = 5@u_pF
    # RhgGME = 1500@u_GΩ
    # *---------Amplifier input impedance------------------------
    # *artigo_ventura
    Ra = 450@u_MΩ
    # * + Ca = 10p
    # *input impedance dos artigos do \Spira
    # Ra = 20@u_MΩ
    # *----------------------------------------------------------

    # **********************************************************************
    # *       GME & GPE PROTEIN-GLYCOCALYX EDL PARAMETERS
    # **********************************************************************
    # * Chd       capacitance of EDL at interface of glycocalyx-solution  [F]
    # * Rhd       resistance of the EDL                   [ohm]
    # * tglyco    glycocalyx thickness                    [m]
    # * gammaw    correction factor
    # * fscale    scale factor
    # *-----------------------------
    tglyco = 100.0e-9
    gammawm = 1
    ChdGME = ((constants["epsglyco"]*constants["eps0"])*(AGME/tglyco)*gammawm)
    ChdGME= ChdGME*10**12
    ChdGME = ChdGME@u_pF
    RhdGME = (constants["roglyco"]*(tglyco/AGME)*gammawm)
    RhdGME = RhdGME@u_Ω
    # RhdGME = 100Meg
    fscale = 2.5
```

**Note:** The files are like so because the last attempt I tried was using dictionaries. As I said in the beginning, in the versions before I also tried to define all the constants (variables) and equations inside the same class and also in separate classes.
Thank you once more.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [mre] that runs and reproduces your problem. As it stands, `class(object):` is invalid syntax. Maybe include what you tried and ask a specific question?

Comment: It looks more as though `first_eq` should be a function, whether or not that belongs to the class given all its inputs reside outside of the class is a different question too though

Comment: I have edited my question with the asked modifications. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood the problem you're having, `first_eq` is evaluated *when that line of code is run*. Things you do later will not change the value of `first_eq` unless you *explicitly change the value* by recalculating it. So after you've set `constant_2 = 40`, you should be able to do `myClass.first_eq = constant_1 * constant_2` and it should work fine.

```
constant_1 = 10
constant_2 = 20
class TestClass:
    first_eq = constant_1 * constant_2

print(TestClass.first_eq) # Output: 200
constant_2 = 40
print(TestClass.first_eq) # Output: 200 (no change even though we changed constant_2)

TestClass.first_eq = constant_1 * constant_2 # Now actually recalculate first_eq
print(TestClass.first_eq) # Output: 400
```

Alternatively, you could define a function to which you pass the two constants. This is a better solution because you won't have to remember to update the value of `first_eq` every time you change the "constants", because you pass their current values to the function that calculates `first_eq`.

```
constant_1 = 10
constant_2 = 20
class TestClass:
    def first_eq(c1, c2):
        return c1 * c2

print(TestClass.first_eq(constant_1, constant_2)) # Output: 200
constant_2 = 40
print(TestClass.first_eq(constant_1, constant_2)) # Output: 400
```

### Re. *"However how would one approach this when the given constant is present in various equation and I need it to be updated in each equation"*:

In this case, it makes more sense to define the constants as variables of the class. Then, functions of the class can access its variables.

```
class TestClass:
    constant_1 = 10
    constant_2 = 20
    
    @classmethod
    def first_eq(self):
        return self.constant_1 * self.constant_2

print(TestClass.first_eq()) # Output: 200
TestClass.constant_2 = 40
print(TestClass.first_eq()) # Output: 400
```

---

Now that you've added some code to your question, here's how I would write the code:

```
class parameters:
    def __init__(self, constants, constants_neuron, constants_gme, constants_cleft):    
        self.Asomat = (2.0*constants["PI2"]*(constants_neuron["dsomat"]/2.0)*(constants_neuron["dsomat"]/2.0))
        self.Aaxont = (constants["PI2"]*(constants_neuron["daxont"]/2.0)*constants_neuron["laxont"])
        self.ANEURt = (self.Asomat+self.Aaxont)
        self.dsoma = (constants_neuron["dsomat"]/constants_neuron["Ncomp"])
        ...
```

And to use it:

```
p = parameters(constants, constants_neuron, constants_gme, constants_cleft)
print(p.Asomat)
print(p.Aaxont)
...
```

This way, all your calculated values are encapsulated inside the `p` instance of `parameters` class. If you want the same values calculated with different constants, simply pass different `constants_*` dictionaries when you're constructing the `parameters` object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! However how would one approach this when the given constant is present in various equation and I need it to be updated in each equation ?

Comment: @preposteroustomato more updates based on your question update

Comment: To see if I understood your answer, if I were now to iterate for example the parameter (constant) "dmhead" which belongs to the dict "constant_gme" I would do the following:
(before this I would attribute all the class variables of the __init__ function to the respective dicts, and then:)
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    constants_neurons["dmhead"] = i
    p = (......)

Am I thinking right ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful and swift answer, I really appreciate it !